# Display HTML Entities in Textblock

Tags: wpf, xaml, html-entities, font-awesome

I'm trying to output FontAwesome Icons using  `icon-lightbulb (&#xf0eb;)` as the entitiy. It works fine if I hard code it as `Text="&#xf0eb;"` but when I store this string inside an `ObservableCollection` for binding I just receive a string starting with `xf..`

The problem also happens with `&amp;` which doesn't convert to `&`.

I have tried using what was suggested [in this article](http://jacob4u2.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/bind-html-to-textblock-with-html-to.html) - and it worked for the `&` but not the FontAwesome icon.

Does anyone have a clue what needs to be done to achieve this?

**Implementation:**

I have installed the FontAwesome Font onto my system and then embedded this into my Visual Studio solution to use.

I'm using a TextBlock to bind it to a field in an `ObservableCollection`

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="/OceanView;component/Resources/Fonts/#FontAwesome" FontSize="18px" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Path=Image}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FF4A8BC2" />
```

I'm then adding to the Collection

```
NavigationInit.Navigations.Add(new Navigation { Name = "IMAGES", Image = "&#xf187;" });
```

Comment: Can you outline your code or create a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.com) to demonstrate your implementation?

Comment: @nickhar I've included my implementation in my question. I can't use a JSFiddle as this is a WPF, XAML Windows Desktop app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The XML entity corresponds to Unicode code point f187, which is 61831 in decimal. So, you could just use System.Char.ConvertFromUTF32 to create a String which contains a character with this code point.

In code:

```
NavigationInit.Navigations.Add(new Navigation { Name = "IMAGES", Image = System.Char.ConvertFromUtf32(61831) });
```

Comment: Sorry can you please elaborate

Comment: Thanks, that works great. For anyone that couldn't understand how to get the correct decimal conversion. You need a Hex to Decimal converter.

Comment: Shouldn't have to convert to decimal — if you have the hex, just use that?  System.Char.ConvertFromUtf32(0xf187)

Answer (score 0):

There is another way you can convert this code into int and then character.  I was using this in converter. It works for me.

```
   Navigations.Add(new Navigation { Name = "IMAGES", Image = (char)((int)0xf187) });
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the posted answers are actually the right way to handle this in C#. The syntax `Text="&#xf0eb;"` in XAML is simply a way to encode the character having code point `0xf0eb`. C# has character literals as well, it just uses a different syntax:

```cs
NavigationInit.Navigations.Add(new Navigation { Name = "IMAGES", Image = "\uf0eb" });
```

Note that the above uses the character described in the text of the question. The actual code example uses a different one. The syntax for that would be exactly the same, just with a different value:

```cs
NavigationInit.Navigations.Add(new Navigation { Name = "IMAGES", Image = "\uf187" });
```

This is much better than calling the `ConvertFromUtf32()` method at run-time (the compiler interprets the character value and the compiled string thus is already what is needed), or playing around with casting the value as `int` and `char` when what you really wanted is a string in the first place.